# Spark Structured streaming ForeachWriter unable to get sparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, elasticsearch-spark

I'm reading JSON data from Kafka queue usingSpark structured streaming but I need to write the JSON data into Elasticsearch.

However, I can't get `sparkContext` inside the `ForeachWriter` to convert the JSON to RDD. It throws NPE.

How can I get `SparkContext` in the Writer to convert the JSON to RDD?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The methods in `ForeachWriter` run in the executors. You can either write a Elasticsearch sink by yourself, or call Elasticsearch's raw APIs to write the data.

Comment: "With elasticsearch-hadoop, any RDD can be saved to Elasticsearch as long as its content can be translated into documents" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

Comment: You cannot get the RDD unless you write a sink.

Comment: OP should have an RDD from the Kafka DStream.

Comment: @zsxwing I have created spark session within ForeachWriter and it works in local but fails in cluster. Is it right to have another session within ForeachWriter?